# How to plot two time series against each other in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following structure

```
test <- data.frame(
  ID=c("1","2","3"), 
  name=c("A","A", "C"), 
  persons_g1_0min=c(1,2,3), 
  persons_g1_10min=c(4,5,6),
  persons_g1_30min=c(7,8,9),
  persons_g2_0min=c(10,11,12), 
  persons_g2_10min=c(13,14,15),
  persons_g2_30min=c(16,17,18))

ID    name    g1_0min      g1_10min   g1_30min    g2_0min    g2_10min    g2_30min
1     A       1            4          7           10         13          16
2     A       2            5          8           11         14          17
3     C       3            6          9           12         15          18
```

And I wnat to plot timepoint `0`, `10`, `30` of `g1` against  `0`, `10`, `30` of `g2`. With normal plot I can do that with

```
for (ID in test$ID){
  part <- test[test$ID==ID,]
  plot(c(part$persons_g1_0min, part$persons_g1_10min, part$persons_g1_30min),
       c(part$persons_g2_0min, part$persons_g2_10min, part$persons_g2_30min))
}
```

but how can I do this with ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test %>%
  gather(tmp, value, -ID, -name) %>%
  separate(tmp, into=c("A","B","Time"), sep="_") %>%
  spread(B, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=g1, y=g2, group=ID)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ID)
```